# React Native: Text element in component cant be centered responsively

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, text, native

I want the Text element to be in the center of the screen. It isnt working. Not even GPT knows any solution.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Text, HStack, Icon, Image, View } from 'native-base';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import ReturnButton from '../components/ReturnButton.js';
import Images from '../assets/index.js';
import ResetButton from './ResetButton.js';

const ScreenTitle = ({ icon, title, nav, restartBtn }) => {
  // const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  let element;

  if(icon != undefined) {
    if(icon.includes("Images")) {
      element = <Image source={icon} size={39} /> // FIXME: Does not work
    } else {
      element = <Icon as={FontAwesome} name={icon} size={9} color={'black'} solid marginLeft={'10%'} />
    }
  }

  return (
    <HStack style={style.container}>
      <ReturnButton onPressFunction={() => nav.goBack()} />
      {element}
      <Text style={style.txt} bold>
        {title}
      </Text>
      {restartBtn == 'yes'? <ResetButton onPressFunction={() => nav.navigate("MyCases")} /> : null}
    </HStack>
  );
};

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 15,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    marginLeft: '10%',
    marginRight: '10%',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  txt: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

export default ScreenTitle;
```

I tried assigning it to a View element as parent and some other stuff. It looked good but it was a bit more to the right, because there are two icon elements on the left, which is why the text element wasnt centered correctly, it was centered to the space it has, not to the actual display size.

Answer (score 0):

Set flex: 1 to container and justifyContent: center

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.